# Generic class parameters used as restrictions on member generic types

Tags: c#, interface

The app I'm developing needs to be able to pull from several different data sources, including a couple SQL databases. Not ideal, but it's an app designed to integrate several existing applications under one roof so I have to work with the schema I have.

Anyway, I'm using the Repository model, and setting up a repository per data source so I only have to make and keep the connections I need at any given point. So, I have to split up my domain model according to the repository that saves a particular domain object, and I have to enforce that objects passed to a generic `Save<T>` and `Query<T>` method are of a type it can actually work with. I tried this, and lo and behold, it compiles:

```
public interface IDomainObject{...}
public interface IOneDomainObject:IDomainObject{...}
public interface IAnotherDomainObject:IDomainObject{...}

public interface IRepository<TRest> where TRest:IDomainObject
{
   ...
   public void Save<T>(T objectToSave) where T:class,TRest //<-- sweet! Didn't think that would work!
   public IQueryable<T> Query<T>() where T:class,TRest
   ...
}

public interface ISecurityRepository:IRepository<IOneDomainObject>{}
public interface IOtherRepository:IRepository<IAnotherDomainObject>{}
```

So I'm feeling clever, however I'm sure Occam's Razor applies here somewhere. Does this smell, or is it a valid way to define common functionality across classes that act on diverging object hierarchies?

Comment: It's a great way, especially for repositories - i use the same setup (`IRepository<T> where T : IAggregateRoot`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code like this is the very reason that generics were added to C# in the first place.  Common algorithms applied to different types.

Comment: Well sure, but I'd never heard of one generic parameter being used to control another before I tried this out.

Answer (score 0):

Echoing RPM1984, I have seen (and used) this method many times it works great. Especially for repositories.